# Solar sail for a 3U cubesat: do we have to buy one or can we design one?

Tags: cubesat, solar-sail

We are working on a *conceptual design* for a 3U CubeSat with solar sail propulsion; we aren’t actually building one or buying one.

However we still need to make decisions like whether to build our own solar sail from scratch or to buy one.

So there's two parts to my question:

1. Is it even possible to make our own solar sail?
2. If so, how do we determine how big we need it to be and what materials might be suitable?

Comment: I've adjusted the wording of your question so that it fits the site better. I've narrowed it down to the making one and choosing size and materials. Your other question about how to *deploy* a solar sail from a 3U cubesat (folding or other methods) should be asked as a separate question. Please feel free to adjust the wording further.  *Thanks!*

Comment: What you are asking about is a build vs buy decision (some call it buy vs build rather than build vs buy). Of course you can build your own. A few decades ago that was the only way to do it. Whether you want to do so now is part of your research.